# Uploading file with Octoprint API and GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, guzzle, octoprint

I am trying to upload a gcode file to my octoprint via its API.
Link to its documentation here: http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/api/files.html#upload-file-or-create-folder

Octoprint responds with an internal server error.
Upon checking its logfile i found following lines indicating an issue in octoprints upload function

```
 File "/home/pi/oprint/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OctoPrint-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/octoprin$
added_file = fileManager.add_file(FileDestinations.LOCAL, futureFullPathInStorage, uploa$
File "/home/pi/oprint/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OctoPrint-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/octoprin$
self._analysis_queue.dequeue(queue_entry)
File "/home/pi/oprint/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OctoPrint-1.3.4-py2.7.egg/octoprin$
if not entry.type in self._queues:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'
```

I am using GuzzleHttp to upload the file, calling the api url /api/files/local

```
public function printFile(Raspi $raspi,$file) {
    $fileName = basename($file); 

    $result = $this->callAPIMethod($raspi, '/api/files/local', [
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name'     => 'file',
                'contents' => Storage::get($filePath),
                'filename' => $fileName
            ],
            [
                'name'     => 'print',
                'contents' => true,
            ]
        ]  
    ],"post");
    $raspi->status = "druckt";
    $raspi->save();
}

private function callAPIMethod(Raspi $raspi,$apiPath,$commandParams,$method='get') {
    $client = new Client(); 
    $apiKey = $raspi->key;
    $params = [ 
        'headers' => [
            'X-API-Key' => $apiKey,
        ]
    ];
    if($commandParams != NULL)
        $params = array_merge ($params, $commandParams);
    switch($method) {
        case "get":    
            return $client->get($raspi->ip.":".RaspiApiController::$APIPORT."/".$apiPath, $params);
        break;
        case "post":    
                return $client->post($raspi->ip.":".RaspiApiController::$APIPORT.$apiPath, $params);
        break;
        case "delete":    
            return $client->delete($raspi->ip.":".RaspiApiController::$APIPORT."/".$apiPath, $params);
        break;
        default:
            return $client->get($raspi->ip.":".RaspiApiController::$APIPORT."/".$apiPath, $params);
        break;
    }
}
```

How do i have to change my Request in Guzzle to prevent this error from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the uploaded file did not have the correct file extension and the octoprint api simply crashed upon sending a file with the wrong extension.

Only .gcode files can be uploaded correctly by the octoprint api, as far as my testing has shown.